# Is there a comprehensive listing/documentation of Solr REST APIs?

Tags: api, rest, solr

Looking for a resource like Swagger, where I could immediately lookup APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr does not provide Swagger like utility for the rest api.

But it has good documentation for the collection and config apis.

The Collections API is provided to allow you to control your cluster, including the collections, shards, replicas, backups, leader election, and other operations needs.

You can refer the collection API [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/collections-api.html)

The Configsets API enables you to upload new configsets to ZooKeeper, create, and delete configsets when Solr is running SolrCloud mode.

You can refer the config API [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/configsets-api.html)

The Schema API allows you to use an HTTP API to manage many of the elements of your schema.

You can refer the Schema API [Documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-api.html)